# Inverse a function set in Python

Tags: python, function, set, variable-assignment

I need help with my assignment on function sets.
I am supposed to create a method that will take a function set and return as an inverse function set.

A function set:

```
f = [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]
```

Should return:

```
fInv = [[4,1],[5,2],[6,3]]
```

Here is my code:

```
def inverse(f):
  fInv = []
  for i in range(len(f)):
    count = len(f[0])
    for j in range(len(f[0])):
      fInv[i][j] = f[i][count]
      count-=1
    return fInv
  return None

f = [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
print(inverse(f))
```

When running, it shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 11, in <module>
File "python", line 5, in inverse
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am still new to coding with python, so please understand that the problem may be a simple logic error.

Comment: `count = len(f[0])`. You mean `len(f[0])-1`?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about that. I understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [list.reverse()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method:

> Reverse the elements of the list, in place.

```
f = [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
for i in f:
    i.reverse()

print f
```

Output:

```
[[4, 1], [5, 2], [6, 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution will be to use a list comprehension that unpacks each pair and then repacks in the the opposite order:

```
>>> f = [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
>>> [[b, a] for [a, b] in f]
[[4, 1], [5, 2], [6, 3]]
```